# OrientDB Delete network BigData

Tags: performance, graph, orientdb, bigdata

I m using orientdb  community version 2.2.20 . 
I have import a large dataset of for about 15M edges and 30K vertices 
What is the best way to delete a graph is it to delete edges , and then the vertices ? or is there a way to delete the whole graph at once?

Reading the documentation I only  find the `DELETE VERTEX, and EDGE` commands

Comment: You can use delete edge and than delete vertex commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're deleting everything, you can use also the `TRUNCATE CLASS` command specifying also UNSAFE. That is much faster. Example to delete any vertices and edges in your database:

```
TRUNCATE CLASS V POLYMORPHIC UNSAFE
TRUNCATE CLASS E POLYMORPHIC UNSAFE
```

Comment: Thank you that's much faster

Comment: Be warned that this will delete all Vs and Es. If you actually have a graph concept and you have multiple graphs with Vs and Es in them then you will need to be more specific about what you delete as well as how you represent a "graph".

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't exist a command that delete the entire graph but you can do :

```
DELETE Edge E
DELETE Vertex V
```

It will delete all the Edge and all the Vertex.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I will test that , Thank you @Pierre

Comment: Does not work saying Error parsing query: DELETE Edge IE DELETE Vertex VP ^ Encountered " <DELETE> "DELETE "" at line 1, column 26. Was expecting one of: <EOF> <WHERE> ... <LIMIT> ... <BATCH> ... ";" ... <WHERE> ... <LIMIT> ... <BATCH> ... DB name="DBs"

Comment: You must do it one by one

Comment: yes it worked but takes too long , is there anyway to make it faster ?

Comment: I don't think so.. You can delete the database and recreate it but you'll need to recreate the schema.